# The relation between $T^{\alpha\beta}$ and its trace

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, trace

I have a simple question. Is it true?
$$T^{\alpha\beta}T_{\alpha\beta}=T^2$$
Where $T$ is the trace of $T^{\alpha\beta}.$
I think they are different.

Comment: Try it yourself with this two-by-two example, $$T=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ The left-hand side of your proposed equation is two, while the right-hand side is zero.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty , would U please guide me. I cannot ask anything :(

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is there some prompt that prevents you from posting questions? If so, please link to a screenshot of that prompt; without further information, it will be extremely difficult to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: Dear Emilio It is OK now. I think the site has banned me! I don't know why :/

Comment: It sounds like you ran into this https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/, but as I said, without further details, there's pretty much nothing at all that we can do to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T_{\alpha\beta}T^{\beta\gamma} =  T^2{_\alpha^{~~\gamma}}$, $T_{\alpha\beta}T^{\alpha\beta}$ is the trace of the squared tensor $T^2_{\alpha\beta}$, rather than the square of the trace of $T_{\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: @my2ets: I have supposed, $T$ is the trace of $T_{\alpha\beta}$

Comment: In that case your expression is not an equality: $T_\alpha^\alpha T_\beta^\beta \neq T_{\alpha\beta} T^{\alpha\beta}$.

Comment: How about this? Is it true? $$T^{\nu\mu}T_{\nu\mu}-T_{\alpha\beta}T^{\alpha\beta}=0$$

Comment: That is trivially true.

Comment: This cannot be correct - OP defines $T=T_\alpha^{\ \alpha}$, i.e. a scalar, which cannot have a trace.

Comment: By $T^2$ I meant the tensor. Confusion is possible but this should be clear from the context.

Comment: So you're saying that it's OK because you answered a completely different question?

Comment: No, and you misrepresent my answer. I edited it to clarify it to satisfy even the most demanding reader.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty This answer was posted before OP clarified what they meant by $T$. In principle, it is not absurd to regard $T$ as the abstract tensor instead of its trace, and so $\mathrm{tr}(T^2)=T^{ab}T_{ab}$ is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see these expressions differ is to note that $T=T^{\alpha\beta}g_{\alpha\beta}$, so you're asking whether $T^{\alpha\beta}T^{\gamma\delta}g_{\alpha\gamma}g_{\beta\delta}$ is equal to $T^{\alpha\beta}T^{\gamma\delta}g_{\alpha\beta}g_{\gamma\delta}$.